# Splitting a column of strings and counting the number of words with pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

```
id   string   
0    31672;0           
1    31965;0
2    0;78464
3      51462
4    31931;0
```

Hi, I have that table. i would like to split the string table by the ';', and store it to the new column. the final column shold be like this

```
 id   string   word_count
0    31672;0    2       
1    31965;0    2
2    0;78464    2
3      51462    1
4    31931;0    2
```

it would be nice if someone knows how to do it with python.

Comment: Are you looking for `df['string'].str.count(';') + 1`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. but that is not what i'm looking for. that code will write "1" to the "word_count" column if the "string" column value is an empty string :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**
The basic solution using `str.split` + `str.len` -

```
df['word_count'] = df['string'].str.split(';').str.len()
df

     string  word_count
id                     
0   31672;0           2
1   31965;0           2
2   0;78464           2
3     51462           1
4   31931;0           2
```

---

**Option 2**
The clever (efficient, less space consuming) solution with `str.count` -

```
df['word_count'] = df['string'].str.count(';') + 1
df

     string  word_count
id                     
0   31672;0           2
1   31965;0           2
2   0;78464           2
3     51462           1
4   31931;0           2
```

Caveat - this would ascribe a word count of 1 even for an empty string (in which case, stick with option 1).

---

If you want each word occupying a new column, there's a quick and simple way using `tolist`, loading the splits into a new dataframe, and concatenating the new dataframe with the original using `concat` -

```
v = pd.DataFrame(df['string'].str.split(';').tolist())\
        .rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1)\
        .add_prefix('string_')

pd.concat([df, v], 1)

     string  word_count string_1 string_2
id                                       
0   31672;0           2    31672        0
1   31965;0           2    31965        0
2   0;78464           2        0    78464
3     51462           1    51462     None
4   31931;0           2    31931        0
```

Comment: @AldemuroMandalamuriAbdulHar Thanks, I should assume every clever solution comes with its own set of caveats.

Comment: Done, its not grey anymore :D

Comment: @AldemuroMandalamuriAbdulHar Cheers, happy holidays :-)